# Excel - Forumla - If Statement

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to create a formula that will tell me if a loan has at least 1 open matter.

I have loan numbers in Column "A", there are multiple duplicates due to column "B", which can reflect several open or closed matters.

```
Loan    Case Status
1234    Open
1234    Open
1234    Closed

4567    Closed
4567    Closed
```

In this example, I need to be able to identify that loan 4567 is an issue because it is closed and it should have at least 1 Open Matter. Where as loan 1234, while it has a closed case, is ok because it has at least 1 Open matter, in this case 2, which is fine.

Comment: So basically, for each Loan, they should have at least one "Open" case status?

Comment: Do you need to create a Master List of unique Loan Numbers as a table elsewhere in the same sheet and then against each Unique Loan Number reflect the status based on your mentioned criteria?

Comment: Bruce - Yes I need to see that they have at least 1 Open Case Status.

Comment: @BruceWayne - Yes as long as there is atleast 1 Open Case. Basically these are on the list because a Hold was approved. So if a hold is approved un Column D, than there needs to be at min 1 open case in Column B. If Column B reflects only Closed cases, then that's what I need to report on because there should not be a "YES" in the Approved field. I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Without making any changes to your data, you can set up two extra "helper" columns.

Assuming your data starts in A1, place this formula in a column to get a unique ID. (I'm using column D, formula starts in D2):

`=INDEX(loanID,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,loanID),0))`

Enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> and drag down.

Then, next to that, you can do `=IF(D2<>0,IF(COUNTIFS(loanID,D2,caseStatus,"Open")>0,"Has Open","No Open Status!"),"")`
[image]

[image]

Note: This can be a little easier if you have no empty rows breaking up the data, *or*, copy the loan column, place in D, then run "Remove Duplicates" on that.  That will get rid of that errant `0` in the "Unique Loan" column. Then you don't need the `If(D2<>0` bit of the `If` formula.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all Loan to another column G and remove duplicates
In H2 (G2 your first Loan) write the following:

`=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,G2,$B$2:$B$12,"Open")>=1,"Open","All Closed")`

Countifs count the Loan equal to G2 and where the Case Status is Open
If the answer is 1 or more it means you have Open
If the answer is less it means All Closed
The If will give you Open or All Closed
A2:A12 is the Loan column (you can use $A:$A)
B2:B12 is the Case column (you can use $B:$B)

If you prefer to have a column C in the same Data as Loan and Case you can use the following in C2:
`=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,A2,$B:$B,"Open")>=1,"Open","All Closed")`

In C3 write:

`=IF(OR(A3=A2,A3=""),"",IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,A3,$B:$B,"Open")>=1,"Open","All Closed"))`
and drag it down